# Bookshelf andWhere / orWhere syntax problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, model, bookshelf.js

```
await bookshelf
    .model('User')
    .where({ org_id: this.get('id'), isAdministrator: 1 })
    .fetchAll()
    .then...
```

This works and selects those records with a certain `org_id` and for which `isAdministrator` equals 1.

I would like to expand this `.where` line in such a way that it also selects associates and partners. I expected he following code to work:

```
await bookshelf
    .model('User')
    .query({
        where: { org_id: this.get('id'), isAdministrator: 1 },
        orWhere: { org_id: this.get('id'), isAssociate: 1 },
        orWhere: { org_id: this.get('id'), isPartner: 1 }
    })
    .fetchAll()
    .then...
```

However, it only selects administrators and partners, but not associates. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can give debug options to see the actual query being made like this:`.fetchAll({debug:true})`. However, having done testing myself, I have found no error in your code and it successfully fetches the row where `isAdministrator` is 0 and `isAssociate` is 1. Perhaps you should share the full code? or maybe there's a missing row in db?

Comment: The resulting debugged sql code is as following:
```'select `users`.* from `users` where `org_id` = ? and `isAdministrator` = ? or (`org_id` = ?
 and `isAssociate` = ?)' ```
Which looks fine for me.

Comment: Thanks! This returns: `'select \`users\`.* from \`users\` where \`org_id\` = ? and \`isAdministrator\` = ? or (\`org_id\` = ? and \`isPartner\` = ?)'`. So it seems to ignore the first `orWhere`...

Comment: Oh, there are 3 or clauses, I did not see. The problem is that the argument of `.query` function: `{
        where: { org_id: this.get('id'), isAdministrator: 1 },
        orWhere: { org_id: this.get('id'), isAssociate: 1 },
        orWhere: { org_id: this.get('id'), isPartner: 1 }
    }` is invalid javascript object, because javascript object can not have multiple same keys. I'm sure there are ways to circumvent this, and I will post it as an answer.

Comment: Maybe use `.whereRaw` and write the correct raw sql query...

Comment: Looks like you have deleted the post on the other site. If you found my work helpful, could you reopen it for me? I have spent nontrivial amount of time into this.

Comment: That's another answer someone deleted, not the question :) Am testing your answer right now, will accept it soon!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219899/discussion-between--and-marty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the argument of `.query` function:

```
{
        where: { org_id: this.get('id'), isAdministrator: 1 },
        orWhere: { org_id: this.get('id'), isAssociate: 1 },
        orWhere: { org_id: this.get('id'), isPartner: 1 }
}
```

is invalid, because javascript object can not have multiple same keys. Do instead:

```js
bookshelf.model('User').query((queryBuilder) => {
    queryBuilder
        .where({ org_id: this.get('id'), isAdministrator: 1 })
        .orWhere({ org_id: this.get('id'), isPartner: 1 })
        .orWhere({ org_id: this.get('id'), isAssociate: 1 });
    }).fetchAll({debug: true}).then(function(users){
        //...
})
```

---